# Specific divisions and range on Y axis using pChart

Tags: php, pchart

I am making a script to generate a plot graph. It will hold values between 1 and 10. My problem is that I want the Y axis to go from 1 to 10 with a step of 1, and by default it ranges between the minimum value and the maximum.

I tried to fiddle with it for a while using [this documentation article](http://wiki.pchart.net/doc.doc.draw.scale.html), but I am now truly stuck.

*edit* 
This far I've got so far as to getting the Y axis to start from 0.

Comment: Your graph is not going from 1-10, but something else?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to fix this by making a transparent serie of data, holding the maximum value.

Answer (score 2):

Old, but

```
drawScale(...,"Mode"=>SCALE_MODE_MANUAL,"ManualScale"=>array(0=>array("Min"=>1,"Max"=>10)),...);
```

gets the chart to graph the right range